# Is there an easy way to resize screenshot in macOS markup editor?

Tags: macos, catalina, preview, screen-capture, markup

When you take a screenshot by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, a preview pops up on bottom right. If you click it a program opens up, which I believe is called markup editor. Now in this program you can do most things. However, I've not been able to find a way to resize the screenshot.

How do I find an easy way to resize the screenshot? I am running macOS Catalina.

Comment: Are you wanting to _crop_ or _scale_ the screenshot?

Comment: scale the image

Comment: I suggest that you avoid doing that if possible and use the software where you embed it to tell it a display size. Scaling a bitmap multiple times can introduce image flaws.

Comment: no i really need it to scale, so i can paste in slack and it's readable without having to click it and then zooming in too much work for all users

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick addition to [@NimeshNeema's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387742/370380), you can directly open your screenshot in Preview using the button on the top right of the "markup editor"
[image]

Comment: Adding to that, if you press CMD+SHIFT+5 and select Preview from Options on the bottom. Then the next time you press CMD+SHIFT+4 and take a screenshot it will directly open in the preview app.

Comment: Very interesting. Did not know that

Comment: I mean i found out about it today

Answer (score 2):

The markup editor doesn't have a control to resize screenshot. Instead you can skip clicking on the screenshot and let it get saved (which is by default on Desktop). Once it is saved, you can open it in Preview.app and use the **Adjust Size...** command under the Tools menu to resize it.

[image]

Comment: I found out that if you press CMD+SHIFT+5 and select Preview from Options on the bottom. Then the next time you press CMD+SHIFT+4 and take a screenshot it will directly open in the preview app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the markup editor but you could open the screenshot in Preview and resize it there. Once in Preview go to the tools menu item and click on adjust size. I'm currently running High Sierra so I don't have access to the markup editor but if you can't do it in markup editor this method will work.